# Upload sharepont Video programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

```
       namespace ConsoleApplication3
       {
       class Program
       {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        using (var site = new SPSite("http://contoso/sites/teams"))
        {
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                  var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Videos");
                  var videoProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                  videoProperties["Keywords"] = "Intranet Video";
                  //videoProperties["AlternateThumbnailUrl"]   = "/_layouts/images/preview.jpg";
                  UploadVideo(list, @"C:\Downloads\Video3.mp4", videoProperties);
            }
        }
    }



                    public static void UploadVideo(SPList list,string      fileName,IDict   ionary<string,object> properties)
            {
          SPFile file;
          using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
          {
           var urlOfFile = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, Path.GetFileName(fileName));
        file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(urlOfFile, fileStream, true);
       }
        list.Update();
    //listid = list.ID.add();
       SPListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(file.ListItemAllFields.ID);
    //SPListItem listItem = list.GetItems("Video3");

            var videoContentType = list.ParentWeb.Site.RootWeb.AvailableContentTypes["Video"];
       // listItem["ContentTypeId"] = videoContentType.Id;

          foreach (var property in properties)
       {
        listItem[property.Key] = property.Value;
       }
       listItem.Update();
      }
       }
     }
```

in this code "SPListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(file.ListItemAllFields.ID);
" im getting null reference exception.an i have tried with other line "var listItem = file.ListItemAllFields;"
same error.any one help me to get solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please explain why you tagged the question with sharepoint-online & sharepoint-apps tags and uses SSOM in your example?

Comment: i have tried SPListItem listItem=file.Item; Same Null reference exception error.

Comment: What is the value of 'urlOfFile' and does the file upload successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call GetItemById, once you upload the file you will be able to access its List Item.

Try this:

```
public static void UploadVideo(SPList list,string fileName,IDictionary<string,object> properties)
            {
       SPFile file;

       using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
       {
        var urlOfFile = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, Path.GetFileName(fileName));
        file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(urlOfFile, fileStream, true);
       }

       SPListItem listItem = file.Item; // Reference to List Item

       foreach (var property in properties)
       {
        listItem[property.Key] = property.Value;
       }
       listItem.Update();
       file.Update();
      }
```